# Group by one column and then average each of the rest of the columns. Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

There are two things I'm trying to do so that I can take the mean of each of 144 columns for each group in the dataframe.

I have 144 columns for different pressure readings, and then a column for 'cycle'. There are around 70 cycles. I want to group the dataframe by 'cycle' and then calculate the mean of each column for each cycle.

I have successfully grouped the data using:

```
cycles = df.groupby('cycle')
```

I am also having trouble with the logic for taking the average of each of the remaining columns as the following averages all the columns together which isn't what I want:

```
for cycle, group in cycles:
    cycles.mean()
```

I'd appreciate any help to do this or a simpler method if there is one.

Comment: For the first error are you sure you are using parentheses for astype: `astype()` and **not** brackets, `astype[]`, in your actual code?

Comment: Yes, definitely using normal parentheses. First thing I checked! :)

Comment: Well then perhaps `df` isn't a DataFrame? I'd check that right before the loop. Otherwise that code does work without issue on something like: `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[f'pressure{i}' for i in range(200)])`

Comment: df is definitely a dataframe, I've checked that. I am converting existing data into floats, so I don't want to create a new df

Comment: Weirdly, I've rewritten my code and it's no working. Not sure what I've done differently! Now I just need to find the mean of each column for each group. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to specify the axis along which you want to calculate the mean, like so:

```
for cycle, group in cycles:
    group_mean = group.mean(axis=0)
```

`axis=0` will give the mean of the rows (for each column), `axis=1` - the mean of the columns (for each row)

Answer (score 0):

The for loop will cast all columns as float except the "cycle" column, which I suppose, it is an "object" (string) type.
Then You create a groupy object called "cycles" based on the key = "cycle" then you apply an "aggregate" function, "mean" in your case.

```
for column in df.loc[:, df.columns != 'cycle']:
    df[column] = df[column].astype(float)


cycles = df.groupy("cycle")
cycles.mean(axis = 0)
```

or directly

```
df.groupy("cycle").mean(axis = 0)
```